# Widget update frequency

Tags: android, widget

I know this is easy, but how can i make my widget update every 24 hours this what am presently trying,

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:autoAdvanceViewId="@id/stack_view"
android:initialLayout="@layout/cepf_appwidget_layout"
android:minHeight="100dp"
android:minWidth="180dp"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

24 hours = 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds = 86400000 milliseconds. Put this value to the `android:updatePeriodMillis`

P.S. Your current frequency is 3600000 milliseconds. This is: 3600000 / 1000 = 3600 seconds / 60 = 60 minutes = 1 hour.

Well, it's basic convertion. 1 hour is 60 minutes, 1 minute is 60 seconds, 1 second is 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: thank you for your response, but what is the frequency of what am presently using and please can you explain can this is calculated